# Login and lock screen doesn't work on Freya

Tags: release-hera, greeter

I just updated my system (now elementary OS 5.1.7 Hera), and both the login and lock screen do not work properly. I have three users on this machine but this is what I get when I login or come back from a lock

[image]

no user icons or names, and I completely miss one user.

Comment: FYI you can install elementary 6 odin which is much more recent and still supported.

Answer (score 0):

@PinkCollins. I raised the same question on Reddit elementary forum, looks like it's an issue in recent built.

try the recommendation given on Reddit [lock screen issue on Elementary-OS 5.1.7 Herra](https://www.reddit.com/r/elementaryos/comments/rd3xd9/lock_screen_issue_on_elementaryos_517_herra/)

Comment: thanks, for now I did what is suggested on Reddit, that is: I removed greeter with  'sudo apt purge pantheon-greeter'  and installed the old-style gtk version with  'sudo apt install lightdm-gtk-greeter'